# Pyton3: Calculating SHA3 Works in laptop but does not work in Amazon EC2 server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I've created a script that I need in order to calculate the SHA3-512 of a set of strings.

The line that I use to calculate said hash is:

```
 s=sha3.sha3_512(uid.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest();
```

The import line is simply:

```
import sha3;
```

This works in my laptop. Python3 version is: Python 3.7.2rc1. In my laptop (which runs Debian Testing) I installed the sha3 python libraries from repository.

In my EC2 Instance, Python 3 version is: Python 3.7.1. In my EC2 instance, I installed the sha3 libraries using pip3.

When it gets to the line above this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculateHashIDtable.py", line 62, in <module>
    s=sha3.sha3_512(uid.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest();
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sha3/__init__.py", line 107, in sha3_512
    return SHA3512(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sha3/__init__.py", line 30, in __init__
    self._s = _sha3.sha3()
AttributeError: module '_sha3' has no attribute 'sha3'
```

Anyone have any idea on what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you read the docs? Specifically this part —> “therefore you shouldn’t go through the sha3 module but hashlib instead” since it monkeypatches that library.  https://pypi.org/project/pysha3/#usage

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that pysha3 and sha3 were the same thing. I had not read this webpage and since it worked on my computer